# how to clear multple select box data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear the selected data on multiple select boxes but it won't work for me.

```
<select  name="age" id="age" class="span2 typeahead" multiple data-rel="chosen">
    <?php
        $age_arr = explode(",", $result['age']);
        foreach ($age as $a) 
        {
            $select = "";
            for ($is = 0; $is < count($age_arr); $is++) 
            {            
                if ($age_arr[$is] == $a['age_id']) 
                {
                    $select = "selected";
                }
            } ?>
            <option id="age2" value="<?php echo $a['age_id']; ?>" <?php echo $select; ?>><?php echo $a['age']; ?></option>
            <?php
        } 
    ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="age_val" name="age_val" value="<?php echo $result['age']; ?>" /> 

<input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear" class="btn" onClick="clearFields()">
```

This is what I tried:

```
<Script>
    function clearFields(){
        document.getElementById("age_val").value = "";
        document.getElementById("age").value = '';
    }
</Script>
```

Please advice me how to clear data when clear button clicked,

[selectbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cviQV.png)

Comment: add `event` `$('.your-button').on('click',clearFields());`

Comment: add <option value ="">

Comment: Please chceck my updated answer. Add: `$('#age').trigger('chosen:updated');` Cheers

Answer (score 2):

As you have a multiple select, not a standard select, you need to set the `selected` property of each `option` element to `false`. Try this:

```
function clearFields() {
    $('#age option:selected').prop("selected", false);
    $('#age_val').val('');
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mt2tmvko/2/)

Comment: didnt work for me. nothing happen.. #age_val is a hidden field . #age is the select box. pls advice

Comment: @RinoRaj thanks for editing a fiddle in to the answer, but please make sure it matches the code in the question.

Comment: @rrrr  Please do check the demo

Comment: @rrrr Check the console for errors. As you can see from the fiddle example, the code should work fine.

Comment: That's not a standard select box, are you using another plugin on it? If so, you need to use the methods provided by that plugin to clear the values.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : yes it used jquery-chosen.js

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
function clearFields(){
    document.getElementById("age_val").value = "";

    var collection = document.getElementById('age').getElementsByTagName('option');

    for(var i = 0; i<collection.length; i++){
        collection[i].selected = false;
    }

    // for chosen
    $('#age').trigger('chosen:updated');
}
```

But as long as you using jquery, then you can use code in answer provided by @Rory McCrossan and add to the function: `$('#age').trigger('chosen:updated');`